# Why is including all your files within a theme folder important?

Tags: theme-development

Alright, I know it is important. It keeps things organized and allows you to port your theme over pretty quickly without any problems. However, I have another developer who does this frequently, including files from the root directory of the site. Saying this is sloppy won't suffice. Are there any other reasons you can think of why this is a bad idea? Can it break the site in any way? Is it a security problem?

Comment: It is brittle development if anything changes in your structure. The question is less why should you not, but why would you work against the best practices of WordPress? I would probably fire a developer who kept doing this because it means their code is going to be a mess to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Some developers may want a root level folder for simple SFTP uploading and will allow their n00b clients to access that to add/remove images, pdfs, etc, but otherwise, all calls should be relative to the theme and not relying on structure/elements outside of the theme itself.

[More helpful reading here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes)

Comment: Yeah, these are like `header.php` and `footer.php` files in their own directories outside of the theme.

Comment: yikes! no, no. it won't kill the site, but makes for piss-poor porting to another install and also means that much more time bouncing between directories for management. Good luck!